# Firebug is not displaying in Firefox 31.0

Tags: firefox, firebug

Firebug 2.0 is installed and is enabled for Firefox 31.0, but I am unable to see the Firebug icon within the browser toolbar.
For cross checking I have pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> to launch Firebug, but it doesn't work either.
I have tried with reinstalling the Firefox 31.0 as well as Firebug.

I can't upgrade it to Firefox 36.0.

Comment: Firefox 31.0 and 36.0 are outdated. What's the reason you can't update it to the current version (Firefox 45.0.1)?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is a bug in Firebug in combination with older versions of Firefox, which is also [mentioned in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/DK_bB-2qnFQ/discussion).

Jan "Honza" Odvarko already [provided a fixed version of Firebug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/8004#issuecomment-201313753).

Though I also suggest you update your version of Firefox to the current one (at the moment of writing this is Firefox 45.0.1).